# close connect of netty

Tags: java, netty

I have a project that uses `Netty`, and there're some problems:

If the `connection` is idle for a while, whether the `connection` will close itself or not? if it closes by itself, how can I set the close time?

There's 5 thread,and they send 100 data. They use the same channel e.g

```
 /** release connect*/
    public void closeConnect(ChannelFuture writeFuture){
    if(writeFuture != null){
        writeFuture.awaitUninterruptibly();
    }
    future.getChannel().close();
    future.getChannel().getCloseFuture().awaitUninterruptibly();
    client.releaseExternalResources();
    }

    //write data
    ChannelFuture future = Channels.write(data);
    closeConnect(future);
```

The above code will result in a `closeChannelexception`. My question is: *how can I avoid the exception?*

Also, when I use `ReadTimeoutHandler` at client, and set `timeout` = 5s, and I make threads sleep for 6s, then `ReadTimeoutException` occurs. When i invoke `e.getChannel().close()`, it also creates a `closeChannelException`. How can i handle the exception myself or close the connection without exception?

Answer (score 1):

You could catch `ReadTimeoutException` if the API throws it and then call your `closeConnect(...)`.

Seems to me though, that the channel is already closed; so either just ignore `CloseChannelException` or handle it if it affects the program state.

Comment: I couldn't catch ReadTimeoutException, it catched by netty in the method of exceptionCaught, and this method is invoked in channelUpstream, if I invoked closeConnect(...), it also creates a closeChannelException. I also want to ignore the exception, but my boss couldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

/** release connect*/

```
public void closeConnect(ChannelFuture writeFuture){
if(writeFuture != null){
    writeFuture.awaitUninterruptibly();
}
future.getChannel().getCloseFuture().awaitUninterruptibly();
future.getChannel().close().awaitUninterruptibly();
client.releaseExternalResources();
}

//write data
ChannelFuture future = Channels.write(data);
closeConnect(future);
```

Try to close channelFuture first then channel itself.